# Does one neurotransmitter travel all the way through the nervous system?

Tags: neuroscience, neurotransmitter

Nerve impulses of course go really fast, but the neurotransmitters have to travel through millions of nerves, so how can it go that fast?

Is it a sort of relay with lots of neurotransmitters taking over at each nerve cell, or do the neurotransmitters go all the way from A to B?

Comment: What sparked your question? Were you reading something? Watching a movie? If so, what? A little background might help me answer it in a way that fills the gap you want to fill. The reason I ask is that your question seems to hint at a subtle misunderstanding about what a neurotransmitter is. Have you read [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotransmitter)?

Comment: It's beginners level Psychology. I guess they're more like chemicals that aid passing of electrical signals?

Answer (score 9):

You've got a few things mixed up here:

A **signal** may travel down a pathway, passing through several [neurons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuron) (e.g. around 4-8). However, this signal is not always in the same form: From one end of a neuron to the other, it is merely an *[electric potential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_potential)* which travels down the neuron's [cell membrane](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cell_membrane) (from the [dendrite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrite) to the [axon hillock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axon_hillock), where the cell decides whether to carry the signal on; if yes, a new potential is sparked to travel down the [axon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axon)).

When the potential reaches the end of a neuron, i.e. an axon terminal, it causes [exocytosis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/exocytosis) of [neurotransmitter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurotransmitter). The signal has become *chemical* now. This diffuses through the [synaptic cleft](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synapse) to the next neuron, where it acts on [ion channels](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ion%20channel) in the membrane to cause a new electric potential.

So the actual distance a neurotransmitter travels is only the distance between the two membranes at the synapse, i.e. the synaptic cleft. This is only about 20-40 nm wide, so it's fairly rapid :)

Comment: Huh, thanks! You mention it only being 4-8 neurons. I can't imagine there being so few between, say, the fingers and the spine? How long are these things?

Comment: @DarkLightA some are pretty long. In a human body, they can be [more than a meter in length](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuron#Anatomy_and_histology).

Comment: Wow! I read there are several billion of them? Is this because every nerve ending has its own connection to the spinal chord?

Comment: @DarkLightA Yes, that's probably around the number of neurons you have in total in your body. The actual pathway that a single signal will follow doesn't usually comprise that many cells though. Example: pain (e.g. papercut) -> cell 1: sensory neuron from periphery (e.g. finger) towards spinal chord -> cell 2: afferent neuron from spinal chord towards the thalamus in the brain -> cell 3: thalamic neuron into various brain regions (exact number of cells here varies as far as I know) -> result: you feel pain. Could be I forgot the odd neuron here or there in this pathway but that's the gist.

Comment: The bit inside the brain could be quite a lot I think, hundreds or thousands even. Plus, a single stimulus doesn't activate just a single sensory neuron, and there are also cross-interactions of adjacent pathways.